# How to embed chabot in another website as a widget and open it?

Tags: reactjs, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have developed a chatbot using Microsoft Botframework. This particular react project is at one repository. There is another repository for a page developed with Angular which needs to have a floating button or a widget to open that chatbot. How do I accomplish this? [This](https://microsoft.github.io/BotFramework-WebChat/06.recomposing-ui/a.minimizable-web-chat/) is a sample similar to what I want to achieve, but it has both the code at one repository.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by "different repositories" you mean that you want to host the parent page and chatbot UI separately.

You can embed the chatbot UI into an existing page using an iframe. That way your chatbot UI can be a self-contained widget that can interact with the parent page hosting the iframe.

Your iframe code will look something like this:

```
<iframe src="<url for your chatbot UI>" width="480" height="540" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for the respose. Yes, both pages are hosted separately. I am not allowed to use iframe, and I have to find other way to do it.